# MySql Error #1054 when adding new column to table using prepared statement

Tags: mysql, alter-table, prepared-statement

I'm trying to add a new column named lot to a table, but I'm getting error #1054 - Unknown column 'lot' in 'field list'. What could be the problem? Here's the query:

```
SET @lot = (SELECT lot_no_start FROM `systemconstants`);
SET @sql = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ipp_sorted ADD `',lot,'` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT=',@lot);
PREPARE st FROM @sql;
EXECUTE st;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that building SQL in this way is *just* building a **String** that *happens to contain* some text that your DBMS understands.

Your new column name, >>lot<<, is just part of that SQL:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT( 'ALTER TABLE ipp_sorted ADD `lot` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT=', @lot );
```

Leaving >>lot<< *outside* the string literal, the DBMS is trying to *interpret* it as a column in *something or other* (variables being prefixed with '@' signs) but it can't find such a column, so gives up with this error.

Comment: When I do it like that it's giving me a syntax error, maybe it's the version I'm using.

Comment: @JonZee: MySQL does not allow a "select" statement as the value of the AUTO_INCREMENT clause.  You have to execute that statement first, retrieve the value, then build that value into the ALTER TABLE statement.